# Changing another language "et al." to "et al."

Tags: biblatex

I am currently writing in Danish via the package:

```
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
```

Now, in my bibliography, which is done by `biblatex`, it changes the "et al.", when having a lot of authors, to "m. fl.", which is technically correct in Danish. But since "et al." is Latin, it pretty much is what we use in Denmark as well.

So basically, how do I change the "m. fl." to "et al." ?

Answer (score 26):

The string displayed by `biblatex` if a name (author) list is truncated is internally called `andothers`, in English this string is "et al." (in the full as well as the abbreviated version), in Danish it happens to be "med flere"/"m.fl".

If you want to change `andothers`, the easiest way is to add the following lines to your preamble (it is a copy of `english.lbx`'s `andothers`).

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
```

Using this method, however, you can only define one string, this string is used regardless of the abbreviation setting.

---

If you care about the abbreviation setting (that is `abbreviate=true` or `abbreviate=false`), you will have to define your own modification of `danish.lbx`, let's call it `danish-lat.lbx`; put `danish-lat.lbx` somewhere LaTeX can find it.
The file contains the following lines

```
\ProvidesFile{danish-lat.lbx}[2013/10/09 very few Latin phrases for Danish]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{danish}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit   = {danish},
  andothers = {{et alii}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},% controversial, what if all truncated authors are female?
  andmore   = {{et alia}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
}
```

This file tells `biblatex` to inherit all the options and strings defined in `danish.lbx` but modifies `andothers` and `andmore`.
Here, the first pair of curly braces encloses the full (long string) while the second pair encloses the abbreviated string.

To use the latinised version of the Danish language add the following to your preamble.

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{danish}{danish-lat}
```

This tells `biblatex` to load the latinised version of the Danish localisation whenever Danish localisation is needed.

Comment: This worked nicely for me. Thanks!