# format of editor in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to put "ed"/"eds" in parentheses with no dot.  I can do the parentheses, but not remove the dot. How do I remove it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{sidn2013,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Booktitle = {The handbook of conversation analysis},
    Editor = {Jack Sidnell and Tanya Stivers},
    Publisher = {Wiley-Blackwell},
    Title = {The handbook of conversation analysis},
    Year = {2013}
     }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you plan to follow [this MHRA](http://www.mhra.org.uk/Publications/Books/StyleGuide/StyleGuideV3_2.pdf) style? In that document there seem to be dots after the abbreviations?

Comment: Ah, good point. It seems like I need to have a dot after "ed", but not after "eds".  (I'm working through my own institution's description of MHRA style, which didn't make this clear.) Using `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{editors=eds\nopunct}` seems to handle that.

Comment: The `\nopunct` shouldn't normally be necessary there, I believe. It is only needed to suppress punctuation that might follow, not instead of punctuation if you don't want any.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this](https://gist.github.com/moewew/628815aca7c32c9af0b095dc528f429f) first (and very rough) attempt at following the MHRA style. Currently localisation strings are missing, but maybe it can give you some ideas.

Comment: That's terrific - and more progress than I had made on a proper package ;-)  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is added in the `.lbx` (specifically `english.lbx`) file where we find amongst others

```
  editor           = {{editor}{ed\adddot}},
  editors          = {{editors}{eds\adddot}},
```

That means that the abbreviated versions include a dot. And there are many more abbreviations for certain roles that include a dot.

If you only need to change a few stings, you can use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` in the preamble of your file.

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  editor           = {ed},
  editors          = {eds},
}
```

With that command, however, you cannot change the full and abbreviated versions of the string separately. Additionally, if you need to change lots of strings, your preamble might get bloated.

Alternatively, you can define an `.lbx` of your own. Create a new file called `english-dotless.lbx` where LaTeX can find it with the content

```
\ProvidesFile{english-dotless.lbx}

\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  editor           = {{editor}{ed}},
  editors          = {{editors}{eds}},
}


\endinput
```

and all the other strings from `english.lbx` you need to change.

Then in your document issue `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-dotless}` and your new file will be used instead of the standard English strings. (Of course this method works for all languages that have existing `.lbx` files.) For more on custom `.lbx` files see [Changing another language “et al.” to “et al.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137034/35864) as well as [What is the most appropriate way to configure biblatex for use with an unsupported language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864).

Comment: Agh, I had already managed to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` to change "et al" to "and others" with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={and others}}` but just hadn't made the connection with this issue. The answer works perfectly, and taught me a lot.