# How can I change 'et al.' nature style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change the 'et al.' format when I use \citet command in biblatex.

This is my sample code.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ref package %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibencoding=utf8,
style=nature,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false,
sorting=none,
clearlang=true,
natbib=true,
date=year,
uniquelist=false,
maxbibnames=9,
maxcitenames=1
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{CH1_3_m.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    
    cite auther with number \citet{Antia2005}
    
    \printbibliography[title=REFERENCES]
    

\end{document}
```

It gives output like this.
[image]

I would like to change 'et al' format to normal text style.
How can I modify my code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is hard-coded into `name:andothers` in [`nature.bbx` (ll. 216-231, in  v1.3c dated 2018/10/18)](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-nature/blob/ea49cfaf3c3ac0fe71c9a0fa5787b1eb28bb46e2/nature.bbx#L216-L231). You can just remove the undesired `\mkbibemph` around `\bibstring{andothers}`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=nature,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  url=false,
  sorting=none,
  clearlang=true,
  natbib=true,
  date=year,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxbibnames=9,
  maxcitenames=1
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr
    {
      test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
      and
      test \ifmorenames
    }
    {
      \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
      \andothersdelim
      \bibstring{andothers}%
    }
    {}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  cite auther with number \textcite{aksin}
    
  \printbibliography[title=REFERENCES]
\end{document}
```

[image: cite auther with number Aksın et al. [1]]

Comment: Just want to comment that if anyone wants to change the "et al." to something different such as "and coworkers" then replace `\bibstring{andothers}%` in this answer with `and coworkers` for example. Saved me asking a question, thank you and hope this helps someone too.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor If you want to change the "et al." output, it is much better to redefine the bibstring. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137034/35864.

Comment: Indeed, that worked better and reduced my code by about 13 lines, appreciate it.