# Biblatex: et al instead of u.a

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I have a document with a lot of references. I am writing in german and when I use cite or parencite and the paper contains many authors, I get u.a. instead of et al.

[image: screenshot]

These are the packages and settings listed in the main.tex file

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\PassOptionsToPackage{english, german}{babel}

\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
ngerman, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[english, german]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
```

I would like to use et al. instead of u.a. .
So far, I have not been able to find a suitable solution. I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137034/35864 where the question is discussed for Danish, but it's the same for German.

Comment: Strange, it does not work either.

Comment: It should work. And in a simple document it most certainly does: https://gist.github.com/moewew/8d43f7a9b70cc24f13f98ccdd1e87172 gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH6l4.png. Can you please post a *complete* compilable example document (should start with `\documentclass` and should contain a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` body with enough dummy contents - probably just a `\cite`, so that the problem is visible).

Comment: Note that your language setup is a bit redundant and contradictory at the same time: You have `\PassOptionsToPackage{english, german}{babel}`, then you pass `ngerman` to the class, but finally `babel` is called with `\usepackage[english, german]{babel}`. In a simple German document the `ngerman` to the class is enough as the class already loads `babel` (at least in the versions I found). Remove the other two lines. If you have an English and German document, probably best to go with `english, ngerman,` for the class and still remove the other two lines.

Comment: That said,  `MastersDoctoralThesis` is a pretty complex and at times messy template (that has gone through many versions of varying degree of messiness). If at all possible I would try to avoid it and go for one of the more establishes classes like the standard classes, `memoir` or the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above the suggested code should work also for you. It feels a bit meh to close the question as a duplicate when you explicitly say that it did not work for you, but given the current state of the question I still think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I went ahead and voted to close as a duplicate. I know you said the linked answer did not work for you, but I verified that it does in fact work with the snippet you posted (and in simpler documents), so with the information shared so far we cannot debug what might be wrong and the question is in fact answered by the linked question. If you are still having problems, I suggest you ask a new question and include an example document that shows exactly what you tried and how it did not work for you. Make sure that the example is compilable for us.